# How to change the tutorial folder in Orange?

Tags: orange

The default orange tutorial folder is the following:
..\Canopy32\User\Lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\application\tutorials\

What if I want to change this location? Or add another folder?

Also would it be possible to achieve this by simply having a configuration file inside OrangeWidget folder?

Help please,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default location of tutorials, but you can add additional tutorial folders using entry point in setup.py.

First, you need to create a python package containing schema (ows) files. Then you need to add an entry point in the setup.py pointing to the location of the package you have created.

If the package with custom tutorials can be imported using `import my_tutorials`, your entry_point will look like this:

```
ENTRY_POINTS = {
    'orange.widgets.tutorials': (
        'my_tutorials = my_tutorials',
    ),
}
```

I have created a sample add-on that registers additional tutorials. It is available on github:

https://github.com/astaric/orange-custom-tutorials-example

If you download the code and run `python setup.py install`, you will see a new entry in the tutorials.